# spket support for ExtJs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I installed the spket and performed all the steps listed in the below link for setting up the auto completion feature support in Eclipse IDE but unfortunately the suto completion is not working:

http://ria.arunkumarm.com/2010/09/setting-up-eclipse-ide-for-extjs-jquery.html

I believe that i might be missing some jars(may be). Can someone please inform what is the link step 9 refers to? Which library it is talking about? I have completed step 8 by adding the ext.jsb2 file successfully.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to add sdk.jsb3 file for ExtJS 4.

ext.jsb2 is for ExtJS 3

Download latest Plugin of [Spket](http://www.spket.com/download.html).

Refer the configuration [link](http://www.spket.com/extjs.html).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info and the link. Is seems that it has worked. ?Why can't I see Ext when I click the Ctrl+space? I can see all the others such as NaN, Infinity, etc etc but Ext is not there. Is it like in the new version, it is removed? I am stepping new into ExtJs, hence asking this question.